# Building a properly structured query to return an ActiveRecord relation, not an array, for will_paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This is my first question on StackOverflow... please be gentle. I'm just picking up Ruby on Rails and I'm mostly through my first learning project, but I can't seem to get this query built in a way that will work natively with will_paginate.

I have a model structure that includes users, groups, and computers. There is no difference between a user group vs a computer group. A group is a group and includes many users and/or computers through two has_many through relationships. A computer and/or user can be in many groups. Here are my models:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :user_memberships
  has_many :users, :through => :user_memberships
  has_many :computer_memberships
  has_many :computers, :through => :computer_memberships

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
end

class ComputerMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :computer_id, :group_id
  belongs_to :computer
  belongs_to :group
  validates_uniqueness_of :computer_id, :scope => :group_id
  validates_presence_of :computer
  validates_presence_of :group
end

class UserMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :group_id, :user_id
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope => :group_id
  validates_presence_of :user
  validates_presence_of :group
end
```

User and group (only included has_many sections for brevity's sake):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  ...

  has_many :user_memberships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :groups, through: :user_memberships

  ...

end

class Computer < ActiveRecord::Base

  ...

  has_many :computer_memberships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :groups, through: :computer_memberships

  ...

end
```

I'm trying to construct a query to retrieve only the (distinct) computers that are in groups which current_user is also a member of. I was trying something like this in my controller:

```
  def computers_in_users_groups_or_all_if_admin
      unless admin?
        computerarray = Array.new
        current_user.group_ids.each do |id|
          computerarray = computerarray | Group.find(id).computer_ids
        end
        @computers = Computer.find(computerarray).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 30).order('sn')
      else
        flash.now[:notice] = "You are seeing all computers because you are an administrator."
        @computers = Computer.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 30).order('sn')
      end
    end
```

It seems to be working, but it returns an array which can't be used with will_paginate unless I explicitly include array support. will_paginate/array doesn't seem to support the .order method, either. Being new to Rails and to ActiveRecord, I know there has to be a better way to perform this query. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, why not order before paginating?

But, the better, more idiomatic way to approach this with Rails and ActiveRecord is a [named scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments), something like

```
# computer.rb
class Computer
scope :all_for_user, lambda { |user| user.admin? ? Computer.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 30) : user.groups.computers.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 30)
end

# computer_controller.rb
Computer.all_for_user(current_user)
```

You'll want to make sure you've set up solid [association code](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html). You'll probably want a `User` to `has_and_belongs_to_many :groups` and also `has_many :computers, :through => :groups` This simplifies the querying and logic greatly.

N.B. The code above is all off the top of my head and untested, but it should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to scopes. Much appreciated. I'm not sure my model associations are quite correct as I can't call users.groups.computers. I'm using has_many through.

In user.rb I have:
  has_many :user_memberships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :groups, through: :user_memberships

And in computer.rb I have:
  has_many :computer_memberships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :groups, through: :computer_memberships

Comment: Tell me if this is wooly, but your response got me down the right track (I think). I haven't made it a scope yet, but adding "has_many :computers, through: :groups, :uniq => true" to the Users model now allows me to simply call "current_user.computers.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 30).order('sn')" which is working fine. I hadn't thought about directly associating users and computers. Thanks!

Comment: Looks good. Yes, I think user.computers is correct. Told you the code wasn't tested! :D The scope won't be required, but it will make things easier if you have need for this code in multiple locations in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Using jxp's guidance above, although I didn't make a scope as I only need this in one spot, I went back and revisited my models. I just added

```
has_many :computers, through: :groups, :uniq => true
```

to my users model and then was able to call:

```
@computers = current_user.computers.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 15).order('sn')
```

It's working fine now. :D